# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'commandlineproject'

Tags: python, python-import

I know there are a lot of questions like this but still nothing makes sense to me.

```
└── commandlineproject
    ├── commands
    │   ├── add.py
    ├   ├── update.py
    ├   ├──__init__.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── main.py
    ├──myscript.py
```

This is my code in main.py

```
from commandlineproject.commands.add import add
from commandlineproject.commands.update import update
from commandlineproject.myscript import parser_args
import sys
```

And this is a Command line application. I dont know if this relevant or not but this is code which i want to work

```
update(vars(parser_args(sys.argv[1:])))
```

And whenever run it from terminal this is the error i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "commandlineproject\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from commandlineproject.commands.add import add
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'commandlineproject'
```

Comment: When you run main.py, the directory it is in, directory commandlineproject, is added to the path Python searches for modules. So you should have no problem coding `from commands.add import add`. But if you want to be able to code `from commandlineproject.commands.add import add`, then the *parent directory* of commandlineproject must be in the search path, for example by adding it to the **PYTHONPATH** environment variable or it being the current working directory when you invoke main.py.

Comment: @Booboo it actually worked thanks, i only reason i didnt try that before is that pycharm is considering that as problem but when i run the program it worked.